# Can "miss" be used like in "Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects"?

Tags: vocabulary

> Quantitative analyses **miss** qualitative aspects

What does "miss" mean exactly in the above sentence, out of its many definitions?

Do you think that "miss" is appropriately used semantically?

Are there better words instead of "miss"? Could you propose some such words?

Comment: Please do not edit my answer. You changed your question but my answer as is still works as it addresses the plural of the verb miss. Therefore, your edit makes no difference to my point.

Comment: `Do you think that "miss" is appropriately used?`could be understood, as I did, that you were asking if it is was also grammatical. Were this question posted on EL&U you might not have received two answers explaining why "miss" is correct. No one, so far, has said it is inappropriate, which is what you wanted to know as well. And now a user, who responded "correctly" to your request, has now deleted their answer

Comment: @Lambie I downvoted you because you insist on discussing the plural thing which OP has clearly indicated is not his question.

Comment: @rajesun My answer is not so long.

Comment: No, you can reformulate all you want but you have no business rewriting an answer to suit that rewriting. Especially when the rewriting does not affect the question about the meaning of word you are asking about.

Comment: @rajesun There's nothing like showing up late to the game. Why do you think Astralbee wrote that answer? I am telling you **again**. The original question was rewritten. So, it does not matter if my answer has **more in it**.  Who complains about more??

Comment: jewels, "analyses" is PLURAL which may be confusing you.

Comment: Can you provide more context details, please? If this is solely about the specific wording in the extrapolation, why would you doubt it?

Answer (score 18):

The applicable meaning of "miss" here is:

> **3** fail to include someone or something; omit

source: Oxford Dictionary of English

A quantitative analysis *fails to include* / *omits* qualitative aspects.

And yes, the usage is appropriate to the context.

Comment: Actually, this: Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects. is scientifically inaccurate. The two types of analyses are basic types of analysis so one does not "miss" anything. It merely does not deal with it as part of what it is in fact.

Comment: @Lambie so they fail to include / omit them?

Comment: @user253751 No, they are apples and oranges, so neither omits or fails to include the other since their definitions are mutually exclusive. That's the whole point...

Comment: @Lambie I disagree, it's not "scientifically inaccurate".  You're wise to **point out** that the two categories are exclusive, but it's commonplace to use that formulation in such cases.  "Motorbikes miss out on the four wheel experience, cars miss out on the two wheel experience..." sort of thing.  "Vegetarians are missing out on meat ..."

Comment: @Fattie Nope: If you ride a motorcycle, **you are missing out on the four-wheel experience**. It is not the machine that misses anything out: It's the rider or driver of the machine that does. That said, quantitative and qualitative analyses are not in the same category at all....

Answer (score 10):

It is correct. In this context, it means *to fail to perceive, experience, or understand*.

I thought you might not have recognised the word in context because it has been conjugated with a plural noun (analyses) that is related to a singular, non-countable noun (social inequality).

Comment: @jewels - have you considered 'overlook', 'ignore', 'fail to consider', etc?

Comment: @jewels - there is nothing wrong with 'miss', it is completely natural, and I suggested those expressions only to help you understand the nuance of this use of 'miss', as given by [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/miss_1#:~:text=not%20hear%2Fsee,hear%2C%20see%20or%20notice%20something): _Miss [transitive] something to fail to hear, see or notice something_

Comment: I doubt any serious social scientist would write: Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects. Because in quantitative analysis you do not deal with qualitative issues **on purpose**. Ergo, the sentence is misleading in the extreme.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, only people miss things, Types of analyses do not. I guess no one around here has ever done any serious writing.  A type of analysis (quantitative v. qualitative) cannot **fail to perceive, experience, or understand** something.

Comment: @Lambie - I don't really have a problem seeing the author in the work, or type of work: and neither, it seems do Steven Seidman in 'Danger of Pleasure: Victorian Sexuality Reconsidered' (_Journal of Social History_ OUP, 1990): _Degler is not mistaken but his analysis misses the central focus and complexity of the Victorian debate over female sexuality_ and Kofi O. Nti in 'The Managerial Economics of Civil Litigation: A Note'  (_Management Science_ Dec 1986): _his analysis misses the nice reciprocity relationship between optimal budgets and implied learning rates._

Comment: An ill-aimed arrow, bullet or stone can miss its target.

Comment: Of course: ***Degler* is not mistaken but his analysis misses the central focus**. That man's analysis misses this or that. Abd that is not a discussion about quantitative or qualitative analysis **per se** as a type of subject matter. The minute you attribute it a type of analysis to a person, it changes everything. If you are describing the field of those types of analysis, you cannot say miss and make sense. I just don't understand how you don't get that.

Answer (score 5):

Wiktionary sense 9:

> (transitive) To be wanting; to lack something that should be present.
> *The car is missing essential features.*

This is use appropriately, in context.

"Miss" seems to be the apropos word here, I would not replace it.

Comment: Actually, this: Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects. is scientifically inaccurate. The two types of analyses are basic types of analysis so one does not "miss" anything. It merely does not deal with it.

Comment: @Lambie Not dealing with it is why it misses it. Maybe you could say that this is tautological, but that doesn't make it inaccurate. In any case, the question is about the wording, not the statement itself.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't it best to head something off at the pass when it is wrong subject-wise? "To say it misses it", is a misnomer believe me. It's like saying: Deductive reasoning misses inductive reasoning. I mean...

Comment: @Lambie "Deductive reasoning misses solutions that can only be found by inductive reasoning"

Comment: @Barmar Who would say that?? You could say the opposite too. As these are two different scientific methods, isn't it better not to mix apples and oranges? If these questions came up on an exam, most people here would get a D.

Comment: The conversation misses the point -- or does it merely not deal with it? ;)

Comment: @gotube It is always astounding to me that respondents to questions seem to forget context. This happens **all the time** on translation forums (like Proz). People see a word and go into a tizzy translating it, completely ignoring the context where it occurs. This OP will have understood "miss" but will have totally missed the point if writing a paper. But that doesn't bother anyone except me, it would seem. And so, all those respondents have tons of agrees, yet the basic absurdity remains. :)

Answer (score -5):

The plural verb miss is due to analy**ses** being plural. (A singular) X **misses** the point. (The plural) Xes **miss** the point.

Exclusively quantitative analyses of social inequality miss its nonquantitative aspects.

analyses is plural, so the verb has to be plural.

**These analyses miss** the point of the presentation.

VERSUS

**This analysis misses** the point of the presentation.

***Miss something as used here means to "not understand or overlook something".

*He missed my point in the argument.***

Please note, that in this sentence: Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects., there is no scientific accuracy.

Why? Because quantitative analysis does not miss qualitative "aspects" of something. It is the antithesis of qualitative analysis.

**These two types of analysis are two basic ways to survey or measure data collection.** Therefore, one does not "miss aspects of the other". One deals with quantitative things (quantifiable numbers and figures and percentages) while the other deals with qualitative data, usually things like attitudes and opinions.

Comment: @jewels Merriam Webster: 5 : **to fail to comprehend, sense, or experience**
[He or She] missed the point of the speech. Same as those explanations you give in your comment, basically and same as my answer.

Comment: downvoter: tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: Any half-sophisticated reader knows there is a  basic difference  between quantitative and qualitative analyses. So, I'd probably express all this differently.

Comment: Quantitative analyses miss qualitative aspects. is not scientifically valid re these two basic types of analysis. One might write something like: Quantitative analysis and qualitative analysis deal with quantifiable (raw) data and non-quantifiable (raw) data, respectively. There are in fact ways to measure qualitative data but not a part of the basic definition of these two types of data. (I have years of experience in this subject as I have translated tons of sociological texts.